# Common Lisp bytecode or machine code decompiler

Tags: byte-code, decompiler, machine-code

Does anyone know of a decompiler for Common Lisp?

I know most lisp environments include a disassembler. But I don't know of any decompilers.

I would think it should be possible to make a decompiler using the output of the various lisp environment disassemblers so as to not be dependent on the bytecode format.

Comment: Can you upload a small sample program (source code and the binary) to see how it looks like?

Comment: @Igor Skochinsky I suppose I could will have to wait a couple days though. I know clisp and I am pretty sure sbcl generate bytecode. And Sbcl can compile to native code. also it is worth noting that somehow the environment is usually dumped into the binary. ECL translates to C then compiles so it is even more different.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Emacs man page.  While I would expect it to be specific for Emacs Lisp, it's certainly a starting point.  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Disassembly.html

Comment: Yes, it is specific to Emacs Lisp. And decompilation is a bit different than disassembly, although decompilers start with a disasssembly as the first step.